# how do i display more than 1 item with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hello everyone i have made a dropdwon list that displays something on screen when i press a item in it but i need it to display more than 1 thing at a time but i dont know how to do that

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["userId"])) {
    header('Location: ../../auth/login');
    die();
}

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="question bg-white p-3 border-bottom">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center mcq">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="question bg-white p-3 border-bottom">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center question-title">
                        <h3 class="text-danger"></h3>
                        <h5 id="complaintHeader" class="mt-1 ml-2">welke lichaamelijke klachten heeft u</h5>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">klachten</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item Maag" href="#" onClick="changeHeader('Maag')">MAAG</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item Darmen" href="#" onClick="changeHeader('Darmen')">DARMEN</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item Hyperventilatie" href="#" onClick="changeHeader('Hyperventilatie')">HYPERVENTILATIE</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item Hartritme-Klachten" href="#" onClick="changeHeader('Hartritme-Klachten')">HARTRITME-KLACHTEN</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item Misselijkheid" href="#" onClick="changeHeader('MIsselijkheid')">MISSELIJKHEID</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item Keelklachten" href="#" onClick="changeHeader('Keelklachten')">KEELKLACHTEN</a>
               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center p-3 bg-white">
                <button class="btn btn-primary d-flex align-items-center btn-danger" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left mt-1 mr-1"></i>
                        &nbsp;previous
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">bij klachten</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary border-success align-items-center btn-success" type="button">Next
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-2"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
require '../include/footer.php'; //include footer
require '../auth/logout-modal.php'; //include logout modal
?> 
<script>
function changeHeader(s){        
    document.getElementById("complaintHeader")
            .innerHTML = "welke lichaamelijke klachten heeft u: " + s;
}
```

so as you can see in my code i made a dropdown button with a script that when i press something in the dropdown it displays it on screen but i want it to display multiple things

Comment: So which "multiple things" do you want to display? Bits from other parts of the page? Some static info? What??

Comment: Is it just text that you want to display?

`document.getElementById("complaintHeader").innerHTML = "welke lichaamelijke klachten heeft u: " + s;`

Do you just want to add the extra text to this string?

Comment: the items that are in my dropdown i can only display 1 thing from my dropdown

Comment: @Gary with that code i can display 1 item when i click on it but i want to select more things and display them

Comment: Your question is very unclear and unspecific. Please edit the question to include some proper examples of what you want to show and where it comes from. Just keep saying "multiple/more things" doesn't really give us anything to go on.

Comment: So what exactly should it do instead? Keep a list of all the things you previously selected as well as the most recent, perhaps? It isn't clear. Always state your requirements in a non-ambiguous way - we can't read your mind.

Comment: so you see how i made a dropdown with items in it i made a javascript code that when i press a item in the dropdown it displays that item but what i want to do now is when i press other items in that dropdown it displays them to not just change the one that i already prest and sorry my enlish is not that good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple things to changeHeader() function you can pass them as an array and in your function append them to your complainHeader with a map() method or a for loop.

```
<a class="dropdown-item Maag" href="#" onClick="changeHeader(['Maag','DARMEN','MISSELIJKHEID'])">MAAG</a>


function changeHeader(s){ 
  const yourArray = s;
  const Header = document.getElementById("complaintHeader");

  yourArray.map(item => {
    Header.innerHTML += item;
  })

}
```

you can use for loop instead of map() method.

Comment: yes thank you pulse this is what i wanted broski